# Could not find the gcm.jar error when creating App Engine backend => suggests installing deprecated library

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio

Using the Android Developer Studio, I tried creating an App Engine backend from the menu for an existing Android project:

> Tools => Google Cloud Tools => Generate App Engine Backend

The error message was:

> Could not find the gcm.jar. Please install the Android SDK Extra : 'Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library' using the Android SDK Manager.

[image: Error Screenshot]

From the Android SDK manager that library is marked "Deprecated". So what's the right thing to install / use?

Comment: "Google Play Services" appears to have replaced Google Cloud Messaging: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Comment: I have installed Both Google play services and 'Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library' form sdk manager and restarted studio system everything. Still it shows the same error. Please post the solution, if any1 encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Google Play Services" appears to have replaced Google Cloud Messaging and is used instead: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html. That said, I installed the deprecated version also to get the app running.

Steps:

1. Tools => Android => Android SDK Manager
2. Select "Google Play services" from bottom of list
3. Install packages...

Ref: http://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/41

Comment: Google needs to get their documentation updated to be consistent with its SDK, etc.  This is the third problem along the way and I resolved the next one, "repository" is required by Maven.  Now, the next ... import error for javax.persistence.Entity (unable to resolve).  Let's hope this is the last error in the build process.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio [version 5.1.2](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65724) this was fixed! That said, they still haven't updated the documentation.