# GCM.jar android studio

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

Now I am getting this error

```
    Could not find gcm.jar. Please install the Android SDK Extra : 
    'Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library' using the Android SDK Manager.
```

But this library is depreciated is it not??

Comment: ya this is deprecated and stuff related to push notification included in Google Play Services.

Comment: This was fixed in Android Studio 5.1.2! This question is also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967976/could-not-find-the-gcm-jar-error-when-creating-app-engine-backend-suggests-in/22765522#22765522

Comment: Its cool man as you can see below we have an answer.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start **SDK Manager** and scroll down to the section "Extras" and make sure you have installed Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library, if not, install the package.

The package will be installed in the directory **"your_android_sdk\extras\google\gcm\"**

Client code (for example to be used in Android app): **"gem\gcm-client\dist"**

To add the gcm client-jar (gcm.jar) to your Android-project, copy it to the **"libs"** folder in your Android-studio project and right click on the file and select Build Path --> Add to Build Path

Comment: cheers mate, I just thought it mental to have to include obsolete packages... honestly google need to get their docs together!

Comment: Cloud Messaging for Android Library has been deprecated and removed from SDK Manager. How did you installed?

Comment: *Note: GCM Android Services is now obsolete - GoogleCloudMessaging has taken over but if you would like to install it (because you're using Kinvey or another BaaS) just remember to tick the obsolete box in the SDK manager