# Android Push Notification Fail

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I migrated an old project from Eclipse to Android Studio which used gcm.jar for push notifications.

I understand that it is deprecated. But temporarily I want to use the jar file till I change all the code to use the new GCM.

In the gradle file, I added

```
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
```

Though the code gave no compilation errors, the push notifications failed. So, is there a way to use the gcm.jar as of now.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533077/gcm-jar-android-studio

Comment: There is no "Google Cloud Messaging" in my Android SDK

Comment: Try this compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

Comment: @7383 Same result. Push Notification failed.

Comment: please post the error/log message. Looks like your jar is getting included, issue is somewhere else.

Comment: The registration id returned is empty. I don't know how. All these days it was working and now it doesn't.

Comment: The migration may be the reason why it is not working. Try creating a new project with the same name as the application name as stated in this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14544878/5995040) might make it work.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was with the jar file. I replaced the jar file and everything worked.